# Extend system menu in Dynamics AX 2012?

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta

Is there a way to add a menu entry to each system menu in the system?

The system menu is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_menus_in_Microsoft_Windows).

Rationale: provide easy access to recurring logic.

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-the box using regular Dynamics AX development techniques, I don't think it is possible. I also think you shouldn't, it certainly is not best practice.

Consider:

- [Using favorites](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa548439.aspx)
- Overwriting the [task](http://dynamicsax-blog.blogspot.be/2011/04/dynamics-ax-2012-help.html) method on a form to capture shortcuts (you could create hotkeys for your functions or launch a form with functions to perform)
- Add a toolbar to your forms, similar to what workflow does, see `SysSetupFormRun.init` where workflow controls are added to forms.